# Loop run an executable against all elements

Tags: bash, for-loop, fortify

I am pretty much trying to find a way to automate a purge in bulk of multiple apps in my test server. I mounted the server client `fortifyclient` inside a test pod and the pod can communicate  with the server. So the flow:

1. List all my apps and grep all their applications versions id's
2. Purge those application versions id's
3. done

So as a first step I set up my environment variables inside the pod.

```
# set env var locally
export token=value
export scandate=value
export sscurl=value
export dir=/test/bin/./fortifyclient
```

This is my `purge.sh` below

```
#!/bin/bash

# List app, fetch their appID's then purge based on date

for i in $("$dir" listApplicationVersions -url "$sscurl" -authtoken "$token" | grep -P "^[0-9]+" | awk '{print $1}')
do
   "$dir" purgeApplicationVersion -applicationVersionID "$i" -scanDate "$scandate" -url "$sscurl" -authtoken "$token"
done
```

output

```
5513
4659
4658
4688
4685
4686
4687
4683
do
   "/test/bin/./fortifyclient" purgeApplicationVersion -applicationVersionID "" -scanDate "value" -url "value" -authtoken "value"
done
```

As you can see that the first argument is working fine as I get my apps listed but the second argument to purge is not working. As you can see the $i is null and it should be the ALL the elements of the `-applicationVersionID` listed above is empty. I am not so strong in bash and feel free to share any alternatives. I would appreciate some feedback. I know I am close. Thank You

Comment: Unrelated but `grep -P "^[0-9]+" | awk '{print $1}'` could be replaced with `grep -oP '^\d\S+'`

Comment: `awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]+/{print $1}'`

Comment: @Jetchisel Yeah, that works too. The `+` isn't necessary though.

Comment: Tried both recommendations listed not luck. Still same issue listed `-applicationVersionID "" ` is null. thanks again

Comment: See [How to read line-by-line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055) and [Don't read lines with for](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: And as Barmar said in your self-dupe's comments: what is the `value` command, and what's the point of adding its output to three different variables?

Comment: This seems quite unclear. It appears very odd that the tail end of your data file would contain program code to loop over the entries. Or does the command you run output other commands? Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].  Provide all the relevant code, but focus on one specific and concrete question.

Comment: @KarlDiji Both our recommendations were "Unrelated" to your problem. That means that they suggest a way of simplifying (or in some way or another "improve") what you're already doing - but without solving the problem.

Comment: Also, this lacks any useful debugging information. Maybe tweak the code so it runs a single iteration, and show the output with `bash -x`. The symptoms look _vaguely_ like there could be invisible control character in the output from the first command, but not quite; in fact, the available evidence mainly suggests that the diagnostics you do provide have not been entirely faithfully transcribed.

Comment: As litele sense as your "uestion made to most of us, you can't change it into a completely different question after you have received an answer. I have rolled back your changes; ask a new question if you have a new problem. If the system wants you to wait before you are allowed to post a new question, attempting to evade that restriction is also not allowed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I try to reproduce your script behaviour, my script flags an error about the "**$dir**" directory reference withing the **$()**.  If you look at the POSIX references, it will indicate that it cannot expand anything with "/" among other characters.

That may be your problem as well.

This suggest that your **listApplicationVersions** should incorporate any usage of the "$dir" reference, and remove that from the $() expression.  Also, for consistency within your context, you should probably do the same for the **purgeApplicationVersion** script and remove the "$dir" from your purge.sh .

Comment: There is no `@$()`, do you mean the command substitution? But I still can't make any sense of this. Why should `/` be disallowed? What do you mean by "expand" anyway? `*` in a wildcard expansion doesn't match `/` but there is no wildcard here either.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  I fixed it.  As for why, I prefer to let responses from others far more knowledgeable to do that.  Please refer to  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334578/what-is-this-shell-bash-syntax-somevariable-somevalue-somecommand  and other shell documentation.

Comment: You changed it to `@()`; did you mean `$()`? The linked question does not seem to have anything to do with this question, or the text in your answer; did you link to the wrong one?

Comment: My apologies.  I don't know what possessed me to keep the @ instead of the $.   I have made the correction.